# System wont boot..."rmi4_f34: probe of rmi4-00.fn34 failed with error -22" How can I go about fixing this?

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, dmesg

I recently did a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, and have been unable to boot into my machine since. The boot screen hangs on this message:

`) 16 (>)71739] rmi4_f34 rmi4-00.fn34: rmi_f34u7_probe: Unrecognized bootloader version: 13 (`

Fortunately, I have been able to boot up in "safe mode", but I am not sure how to go about fixing this. It seems like a driver error of some kind? I am relatively new to Linux and have gotten as far as checking dmesg (see attached screenshot) but I am not sure where to go from here. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

dmesg:
[image: 1]

Edit:

When it comes to using journalctl to diagnose the issue, would this be something that would be found at the end of the log? Or could the critical failure be found at an point throughout? I've some snippets from the end of each log:

Failed boot:

```
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.379553712-07:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706157284.433:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=1282 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.442294243-07:00" level=info msg="[core] parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.442307403-07:00" level=info msg="[core] scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.442321072-07:00" level=info msg="[core] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.442326427-07:00" level=info msg="[core] ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.442330373-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel switches to new LB policy \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.443055117-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.443069855-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel picks a new address \"unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock\" to connect" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.443658348-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.445870699-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.445881053-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447279972-07:00" level=info msg="[core] parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447291905-07:00" level=info msg="[core] scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447303596-07:00" level=info msg="[core] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447308736-07:00" level=info msg="[core] ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447313869-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel switches to new LB policy \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447323487-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447332473-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel picks a new address \"unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock\" to connect" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447363265-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447421729-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.447429763-07:00" level=info msg="[core] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.473086310-07:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:44.484890988-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows kernel: Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.6637] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8347] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8360] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8381] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (4ce46169-02ee-4a1d-9acc-3fb3c6272fa9)
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8386] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8393] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8399] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8405] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8438] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8447] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 24 21:34:44 ms-windows NetworkManager[996]: <info>  [1706157284.8459] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:45.126675807-07:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:45.245214817-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:45.322338813-07:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=5df983c graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.25+dfsg1
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:45.324129180-07:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Reached target multi-user.target - Multi-User System.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Reached target graphical.target - Graphical Interface.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows dockerd[1192]: time="2024-01-24T21:34:45.346849541-07:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Starting systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP...
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Finished systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP.
Jan 24 21:34:45 ms-windows systemd[1]: Startup finished in 7.228s (firmware) + 2.555s (loader) + 3.224s (kernel) + 9.485s (userspace) = 22.495s.
Jan 24 21:34:47 ms-windows systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:35:01 ms-windows CRON[1424]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jan 24 21:35:01 ms-windows CRON[1425]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 24 21:35:01 ms-windows CRON[1424]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 21:35:07 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:35:07 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:35:07 ms-windows systemd-timesyncd[917]: Contacted time server 209.115.181.110:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 24 21:35:07 ms-windows systemd-timesyncd[917]: Initial clock synchronization to Wed 2024-01-24 21:35:07.754782 MST.
Jan 24 21:35:54 ms-windows systemd-logind[928]: Power key pressed short.
Jan 24 21:35:54 ms-windows systemd-logind[928]: Powering off...
Jan 24 21:35:54 ms-windows systemd-logind[928]: System is powering down.
```

And what follows the "fail point" when I boot into recovery mode:

```
Jan 24 21:37:07 ms-windows systemd-timesyncd[878]: Initial clock synchronization to Wed 2024-01-24 21:37:07.319132 MST.
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' unit='xdg-desktop-portal.service' requested by ':1.62' (uid=1000 pid=2300 comm="/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr")
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Documents' unit='xdg-document-portal.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=1000 pid=2356 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents'
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service.
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-document-portal[2361]: Ignoring invalid max threads value 4294967295 > max (100000).
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Lockdown as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: The preferred method to match portal implementations to desktop environments is to use the portals.conf(5) configuration file
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=1000 pid=2356 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk'
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: No skeleton to export
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.FileChooser as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.AppChooser as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Print as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Notification as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Inhibit as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Account as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Email as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows xdg-desktop-por[2356]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.DynamicLauncher as a last-resort fallback
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
Jan 24 21:37:08 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Successfully made thread 2500 of process 2300 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:09 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:10 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:13 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:13 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1000 pid=1813 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2a006ec25-21f1-4ea4-9ee9-094")
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started tumblerd.service - Thumbnailing service.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1000 pid=1813 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2a006ec25-21f1-4ea4-9ee9-094")
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.xfce.FileManager' unit='thunar.service' requested by ':1.28' (uid=1000 pid=1819 comm="xfdesktop --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 23d753dfc-")
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' unit='thunar.service' requested by ':1.28' (uid=1000 pid=1819 comm="xfdesktop --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 23d753dfc-")
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting thunar.service - Thunar file manager...
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows gvfsd-trash[2842]: GFileInfo created without standard::name
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows gvfsd-trash[2842]: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1699 (g_file_info_get_name): should not be reached
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows gvfsd-trash[2842]: GFileInfo created without standard::name
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows gvfsd-trash[2842]: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1699 (g_file_info_get_name): should not be reached
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.FileManager'
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started thunar.service - Thunar file manager.
Jan 24 21:37:15 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Jan 24 21:37:16 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:37:27 ms-windows systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:39:01 ms-windows CRON[3802]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jan 24 21:39:01 ms-windows CRON[3803]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jan 24 21:39:01 ms-windows CRON[3802]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 21:39:02 ms-windows systemd[1]: Starting phpsessionclean.service - Clean php session files...
Jan 24 21:39:02 ms-windows systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:39:02 ms-windows systemd[1]: Finished phpsessionclean.service - Clean php session files.
Jan 24 21:39:31 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:31 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:39:34 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:40:35 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:40:35 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:40:45 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:40:45 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:43:37 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706157817.3409] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 06:2B:F6:D7:0A:B5 (scanning)
Jan 24 21:43:37 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706157817.3684] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 24 21:43:37 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706157817.3685] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 24 21:45:01 ms-windows CRON[7116]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jan 24 21:45:01 ms-windows CRON[7117]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 24 21:45:01 ms-windows CRON[7116]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 21:46:57 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating service name='org.xfce.Xfconf' requested by ':1.26' (uid=1000 pid=1808 comm="xfce4-panel --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 2c2059e3")
Jan 24 21:46:57 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.Xfconf'
Jan 24 21:48:31 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1129]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.96' (uid=1000 pid=8798 comm="flameshot gui")
Jan 24 21:48:31 ms-windows systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service...
Jan 24 21:48:31 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1129]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 24 21:48:31 ms-windows systemd[1]: Started systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service.
Jan 24 21:48:32 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1129]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service' requested by ':1.98' (uid=1000 pid=8915 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfsd-dnssd --spawner :1.22 /org/gtk/")
Jan 24 21:48:32 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1129]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service not found.
Jan 24 21:48:40 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:48:40 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:48:40 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:48:40 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:48:41 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:48:41 ms-windows rtkit-daemon[1305]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Jan 24 21:49:01 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:50:28 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706158228.3445] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 62:D1:D5:80:CD:44 (scanning)
Jan 24 21:50:28 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706158228.3747] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Jan 24 21:50:28 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706158228.3748] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Jan 24 21:50:28 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706158228.3805] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 24 21:50:28 ms-windows NetworkManager[1184]: <info>  [1706158228.3806] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 24 21:50:39 ms-windows sudo[10148]: jacktripp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jacktripp ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b -1
Jan 24 21:50:39 ms-windows sudo[10148]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Jan 24 21:50:39 ms-windows sudo[10148]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 21:50:43 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' unit='tumblerd.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=1000 pid=1813 comm="Thunar --sm-client-id 2a006ec25-21f1-4ea4-9ee9-094")
Jan 24 21:50:43 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Starting tumblerd.service - Thumbnailing service...
Jan 24 21:50:43 ms-windows dbus-daemon[1645]: [session uid=1000 pid=1645] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
Jan 24 21:50:43 ms-windows systemd[1622]: Started tumblerd.service - Thumbnailing service.
Jan 24 21:51:31 ms-windows systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jan 24 21:51:31 ms-windows systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 24 21:51:31 ms-windows systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 24 21:51:47 ms-windows sudo[10826]: jacktripp : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jacktripp ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b
Jan 24 21:51:47 ms-windows sudo[10826]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
```

The full logs can be found here:

[Failed boot](https://pastebin.com/Qm38CFgJ)

and

[Boot into recovery mode](https://pastebin.com/WQ9iSpq3)

Answer (score 1):

The boot screen hangs on this message, but that has nothing to do with what the boot process actually hangs on – this just happens to be the last message *printed to screen* (because it's the only "error"-level message). Indeed you can see from dmesg that the process continues from there.

RMI is the protocol used by Synaptics touchpads, and RMI function 34 is the *device reflash* interface that's used to update the firmware of your touchpad. Failure to initialize RMI f34 wouldn't even prevent the touchpad from working (that uses RMI f11 and f12), indeed the touchpad is successfully detected as an input device a few lines later.

Even if RMI initialization failed completely it really wouldn't prevent the rest of the boot process from continuing – you would still get graphics and keyboard input, just not the touchpad.

What *really* seems to have failed (even though it did not print any "red" messages) is the initialization of your Intel GPU, as the `i915` driver says that it could not activate the eDP output that connects to your laptop's display panel.

The i915 failure not be 100% the issue if you have a discrete GPU (depending on how the laptop is wired), but it's certainly not normal in general.

Further diagnosis should involve checking the full system log (i.e. not just kernel messages but also service/userspace messages as well), e.g. through `journalctl -b`. If your graphical environment fails to start (you see gdm.service failing), that's also where it should reveal *why* it fails to start – whether it's due to not finding any video outputs or something else.

---

In this case, it's simply that the system as a whole is set to 'quiet' boot, so you see the failure of RMI f34 as the "last" merely because it *complains louder* so its messages happen to be the only thing that is printed on screen.

But that aside, keep in mind that **the boot process is not linear.** Multiple things are happening at once – device detection and driver loading is done in parallel with starting services, of which probably 3-4 are starting all at once – so you should never put too much importance on what seems to be "the last thing".

(For example, if service A fails while services B and C are still slowly starting, you would see B or C being "last" even though A was really what failed.)

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply, I really appreciate it. I'm using the closed source nVidia drivers and CUDA toolkit, which might explain the i915 error. I used ```journalctl -b``` and ```journalctl -b -1``` to load the logs for the failed "normal" boot and the successful boot into recovery mode. It appears...I am in way over my head :( I'd love to learn how to diagnose and fix this issue, would you be able to provide any suggestion as to what someone would look for, in general, within these logs?